# Ensure a class always uses its own version of a method rather than the one defined in a subclass?

Tags: python-3.x, method-resolution-order

I have this code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, vals: list):
        self._vals = vals

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        # some side effects like logging maybe
        return len(self._vals)

    def print_len(self) -> None:
        # some function that uses the len above
        print(len(self))


class B(A):
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return 0
```

The issue is, I want `print_len` to always call `A.__len__`. I can do this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, vals: list):
        self._vals = vals

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._vals)

    def print_len(self) -> None:
        print(A.__len__(self))


class B(A):
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return 0
```

But it feels wrong. Basically I want B to lie about `__len__` to outside callers, but internally use the correct len specified in A.

So

```
a = A([1, 2, 3])
print(len(a))  # print 3
a.print_len()  # print 3 - no surprises there

b = B([1, 2, 3])
print(len(b))  # print 0 - overload the __len__
b.print_len()  # want this to be 3 using A's __len__, not 0 using B's __len__
```

Is there any way to **ensure a class always uses its own version of a method rather than a subclass' version?** I thought name mangling of dunder methods would help here.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is a good one. The zen of Python states that "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." and I think you've found it.

That being said, you can do this via [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). You just need to prefix the method with double underscores (don't add them to the end like magic methods). This will create a private method which won't ever be overwritten by subclasses.

I think this might be self-defeating since you're now putting the computation in a different method.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, vals: list):
        self._vals = vals

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.__length()

    def __length(self) -> int:
        return len(self._vals)

    def print_len(self) -> None:
        print(self.__length())
```

Comment: Funny how dunder methods like `__len__` don't do name mangling despite the leading `__`, confusing syntax